# Do not bug me about questions needing votes too

Tags: script, voting

## Description

Hide the warning that appears after voting on a certain number of answers without voting on questions in-between.

## Installation

[bitbucket.org/.../raw/default/do-not-bug-me-about-questions-needing-votes-too.user.js](https://bitbucket.org/stijnherreman/stack-exchange-user-scripts/raw/default/do-not-bug-me-about-questions-needing-votes-too.user.js)

## Source

[bitbucket.org/.../src/default/do-not-bug-me-about-questions-needing-votes-too.user.js](https://bitbucket.org/stijnherreman/stack-exchange-user-scripts/src/default/do-not-bug-me-about-questions-needing-votes-too.user.js)